# Paste some VBA code via VBA to each newly genereated sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple code that creates a new sheet in template form after running it.
By doing so I get a new sheet with all what I need in my template.

I need to copy aswell a short VBA script Worksheet_Change into that newly created sheets.
For ex. code to get the windows user id and date from system after making change in cells in column B.

How can I put that Worksheet_Change script into my vba code for each new sheet created via VBA?

Comment: Why not use Sub Workbook_SheetChange and limit what sheets use this code by `if sheetName like "something*" then`? that way the code is only in one place. (if there is a need to limit it, or do you want it to run on ALL sheets?)

Comment: All sheet names are generated after that criteria: 2 x letter; XX - Template type; YYY - consecutive number for template type. So it goes like this: CP01001; CP01002 or for other template type CP02001. How should I cover all names? I have 12 different templates and it can be even more in the future

Comment: As I said, should this code run on all sheets then just add it to workbook sheetchange and it will be called whatever sheet has a change.

Comment: If by _creates a new sheet in template form_ you mean you have a sheet you copy to create the new sheet, add the required code into that template sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Andreas said use the workbook sheetchange, and in that you can write a function that adds the user ID and date to sheetname.cells(r,c) - wherever you want - as 'sheetname' is passed when workbook_sheetchange event is called